# Upper bound of infinity sum

Tags: probability

Can please someone explain to me why this transition is right ?
All we know is that $\epsilon < 0.5$

$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-2\log_2 (1/\epsilon) 2^j}
  \le \frac{\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2}
$$

I've tried to simplify this sum and the best i could get was :
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty (\epsilon^2)^{2^j}
$$

This problem is taken from Group Testing academic article , and it's part of the proof of lemme 2 in the article.
[The article](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9OmwPOhT86EME5FcG5mY3Vydk4tSi1ydmtnbDdLMGV3aEUw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please typeset your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: One thought may be to note that $$
-2\log (1/\epsilon) 2^j = 2^{j+1} \log \epsilon
$$
so assuming your notation is $\log x = \log_2 x$, you have
$$
2^{-2\log (1/\epsilon) 2^j} = 2^{2^{j+1} \log \epsilon} = \epsilon^{2^{j+1}}
$$

Comment: thank you for your comment, ive edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Just write out the first few terms, so that you can see a comparison with the familiar geometric series:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty (\epsilon^2)^{2^j}
&=(\epsilon^2)^1+(\epsilon^2)^2+(\epsilon^2)^4+(\epsilon^2)^8+\cdots\\
&\le(\epsilon^2)+(\epsilon^2)^2+(\epsilon^2)^3+(\epsilon^2)^4+\cdots\\
&={\epsilon^2\over1-\epsilon^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Many thanks Barry!